# Hadoop: how reducer nodes are selected?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I just started learning Hadoop, but don't understand how a datanode becomes a reducer node.

- Once the map task completes, the content of its sort buffer is flushed to the local disk
  after the KV pairs are sorted and partitioned
- Then the jobtracker is notified about the spilled partitions.
- After then the reducers start asking the data from a particular partition.

But **how** the jobtracker decides which node becomes a reducer node? I'm reading the *Hadoop Definitive guide* but this step is not mentioned in the book.

Thanks,
Bruckwald

Comment: i think data locality can be what you are searching for.

Comment: @aviral reduce tasks are not assigned by data locality.

Comment: yeahh just saw ..my bad..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty much `first-come, first-serve`. Tasks are assigned by heartbeats, so if a Tasktracker pings the Jobtracker that it is alive, it will get a response that might contain a new task to run:

```
List<Task> tasks = getSetupAndCleanupTasks(taskTrackerStatus);
if (tasks == null ) {
   tasks = taskScheduler.assignTasks(taskTrackerStatus);
}
if (tasks != null) {
   for (Task task : tasks) {
     expireLaunchingTasks.addNewTask(task.getTaskID());
     LOG.debug(trackerName + " -> LaunchTask: " + task.getTaskID());
     actions.add(new LaunchTaskAction(task));
   }
}
```

[Here's the relevant source code of the Jobtracker](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker.java#2629). So besides which tasktracker comes first, the taskscheduler will check for resource conditions (e.g. if there is a free slot, or a single node is not overloaded).

The relevant code can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobQueueTaskScheduler.java#207) (which isn't particular exciting):

```
//
// Same thing, but for reduce tasks
// However we _never_ assign more than 1 reduce task per heartbeat
//
final int trackerCurrentReduceCapacity = 
  Math.min((int)Math.ceil(reduceLoadFactor * trackerReduceCapacity), 
           trackerReduceCapacity);
final int availableReduceSlots = 
  Math.min((trackerCurrentReduceCapacity - trackerRunningReduces), 1);
boolean exceededReducePadding = false;
if (availableReduceSlots > 0) {
  exceededReducePadding = exceededPadding(false, clusterStatus, 
                                          trackerReduceCapacity);
  synchronized (jobQueue) {
    for (JobInProgress job : jobQueue) {
      if (job.getStatus().getRunState() != JobStatus.RUNNING ||
          job.numReduceTasks == 0) {
        continue;
      }

      Task t = job.obtainNewReduceTask(taskTracker, numTaskTrackers, taskTrackerManager.getNumberOfUniqueHosts());                             
      if (t != null) {
        assignedTasks.add(t);
        break;
      }

      // Don't assign reduce tasks to the hilt!
      // Leave some free slots in the cluster for future task-failures,
      // speculative tasks etc. beyond the highest priority job
      if (exceededReducePadding) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Basically, the first tasktracker that heartbeats to the Jobtracker and has enough slots available will get a reduce tasks.